# Learning JS: why is Type error thrown here?

Tags: javascript, typeerror, throw

I'm learning object oriented Javascript and am trying to solve a very simple problem. Given a string, convert it to another using the rules below:

- G >> C
- C >> G
- T >> A
- A >> U

Here is my code:

```js
    var DnaTranscriber = function(){};
    
    DnaTranscriber.prototype = {
        map: {G:'C', C:'G', T:'A', A:'U'},
        toRna: function(dna) {
            return dna.split('').map(this.mapper).join('');
        },
        mapper: function(dnaChar){
            if(this.map[dnaChar]) return this.map[dnaChar];
            throw new Error('Invalid input');
        }
    };

    var d = new DnaTranscriber();
    d.toRna('C');
```

However, trying to execute this code throws an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'C' of undefined

Why is `this.map` undefined inside `mapper`?

Comment: Because Javascript. `this.mapper` is not "bound" to your `d` object anymore. You need `this.mapper.bind(this)` or something like this.

Comment: thnks @georg you're right that works but it's confusing. How could the `this` context have changed though? I'm calling a function within the same object as the calling code right?

Comment: @Hektor the empty function `var DnaTranscriber = function(){};` is the constructor of the `DnaTranscriber`, and it is empty because the OP does nothing in it.

Comment: Your issue is here: `map(this.mapper)`. Passing in `this.mapper` as a callback loses the context of `this` when it is called. try `map(this.mapper.bind(this))` ... ugly but, welcome to OO javascript

Comment: Not related to your problem. But in most cases you want create a named function `function name() {}` instead of assigning an anonymous function to a variable `var name = function() {}`.

Comment: It's because`this.map[dnaChar]` is inside of the function `function(dnaChar){ ...` and the `this` keyword in JS represents the current context.  It reference this direct parent function, not your entire object.

Comment: @Quentin thanks for linking to the Q this one duplicates!

Comment: @ChrisBarr What do you want to say with `[...]It reference this direct parent function, not your entire object.[...]`? The `this` is always the context on which the function was called. In the  case of the `.map(this.mapper)` the `mapper` function will be called  with no context by the `map` algorithm, so `this` will refer  to the global object, in case of the browser it would be `window`.

Comment: @t.niese Using `function name(){}` within `Object.prototype` without assigning it to a named property -- `name: function(){}` -- raises syntax errors

Comment: @BeetleJuice I did not mean the part in the functions in the object definition. I meant that you should write `function DnaTranscriber(){};` instead of `var DnaTranscriber = function() {}` in your case. But this is true in most cases for all `var name = function() {}`  where you have an assignment (`=`) of an  anonymous function  to a variable. For properties of an object it can be useful to write `mapper: function mapper(dnaChar)`, because then the name `mapper` would appear in the stack trace of an error which could make it easy for debugging.

Comment: @t.niese OK I understand. Thanks. Why is it better to use `function DnaTranscriber(){}` instead of `var DnaTranscriber = function() {};`? You say I should do so but not why.